# how to set the necessary permission for my code to use?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a code for packet sniffing in python and in windows 10. According to my searching, I saw that most of the developers said that Linux is better for packet sniffing but I can't use Linux right now, So how could i fix this error?
I tried using `print(ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin())` and it gave 0 value.
This is my code:

```
def main():
print(ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin())
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_IP)

while True:
    raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65535)
    dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)
    print("\nEthernet Frame:")
    print("Destination: {}, Source: {}, Protocol: {}".format(dest_mac,src_mac,eth_proto))
```

And I've got this error:

**OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions**

I know it's something about permission but how can i do that? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Any reason you're not using an existing tool for this, like Wireshark?

Comment: @Barmar NO, nothing sir